# Can I delimit one column to many in pandas at a specific column index location, or move the location of the resulting columns in bulk?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a datafram with 60+ columns. One column (at index 10) needs to be delimited to 6 new columns on the '_' character. I am assigning the new columns like this:

```
df[['col1','col2','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6']] = df['original_col'].str.split('_',expand=True)
```

This works, but adds the new columns to the end of the df. Is there any I can assign those new columns in place right after 'original_col'? or is there a way to move the index of the 6 new cells into a position in the middle of the df in bulk?

I know I can insert a new column into a position using:

```
df.insert(loc, column, value)
```

But I can't do the same for multiple new columns that are assigned into existence. Or I just can't get the syntax right...

Comment: Instead do: `df['col1'],df['col2'],....=.... `

Comment: thanks @yatu, but when I do that I get "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"...

Answer (score 1):

While I could not get this done in one line I solved the problem by adding:

```
new_cols = ['c1', 'c3', 'c2','c6'...]
df_new_order = df.reindex(columns = new_cols)
```

Its a little tedious with 60+ columns, but you can just copy/paste them into order and it works. It seems logical now that you can't just move a col index location into the middle of a df without accounting for where the other cols land...